# What is the best way to wire this specific optocoupler to drive a MOSFET gate?

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator

I am using an [FOD3180](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fod3180-d.pdf) optocoupler.  I want to use the IRFP250 MOSFET to drive a 30V motor. I'm going to power the MOSFET with a separate 12V power supply. Can anyone show me the specific circuit diagram for that?

Comment: Please add a data sheet link to the 30 volts power supply, the 12 volt power supply, the motor, the MOSFET and the FOD3180.

Comment: Why do you need separate power supplies?  Why do you need isolation?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. What is the optocoupler supposed to be doing?